# Debian user learning CentOS: how to install this package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos, yum

After always having worked on Debian I now have to use some CentOS servers. I need to install a package which I always install on Debian servers using `sudo apt-get install python-zbar`.

So I tried running `sudo yum install python-zbar`, but this results in `No package python-zbar available`. Is the package named differently on CentOS, or does it simply not exist?

To find out which packages it installs on Debian I ran `apt-get install --dry-run python-zbar`, which returns

```
Inst libxau6 (1:1.0.8-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst libxdmcp6 (1:1.1.1-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst libxcb1 (1.10-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst libx11-data (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst libx11-6 (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst libv4lconvert0 (1.0.1-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst libv4l-0 (1.0.1-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst libzbar0 (0.10+doc-9build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst python-zbar (0.10+doc-9build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libxau6 (1:1.0.8-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libxdmcp6 (1:1.1.1-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libxcb1 (1.10-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libx11-data (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf libx11-6 (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libv4lconvert0 (1.0.1-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libv4l-0 (1.0.1-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf libzbar0 (0.10+doc-9build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf python-zbar (0.10+doc-9build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
```

Does this mean I need to install all these packages separately? Or is there another trick? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

zbar - as in [ZBar Bar Code Reader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar/)? If so then `sudo yum install zbar`

It's in the EPEL repo so you may need to install/enable that in order to find it. [(Instructions here)](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/)

`yum info zbar` gives the following result:

```
Name        : zbar
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.10
Release     : 7.el6
Size        : 136 k
Repo        : epel
Summary     : Bar code reader
URL         : http://zbar.sourceforge.net/
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : A layered barcode scanning and decoding library. Supports EAN, UPC, Code 128,
            : Code 39 and Interleaved 2 of 5.
            : Includes applications for decoding captured barcode images and using a video
            : device (eg, webcam) as a barcode scanner.
```